# Images getting smashed

Tags: images, gallery

I am developing a web site and I have encountered a problem regarding images and galleries.

Images are getting smashed whenever you enter the page, once you refresh a couple of times, it gets fixed but the first time you enter the page it looks like this:
[image]

When it should look like this:
[image]

The process these images got through was:

1. Upload
2. Place the gallery (Gutemberg Block)
3. Optimize with the EWWW Plugin

After that and regarding the image optimization I have the PageSpped Ninja, Autoptimize, and Smush plugins activated.

I have tried to disable all of them and the problem persists, I hope you can help me with this.

Thank you :D

Comment: try  to lazy load plugin add and  cache plugin

Comment: You're running 4 image optimization plugins at the same time?

Comment: The issue that you're running into is that image script is running before the images are fully loaded. Usually DeSandro's 'imagesLoaded' is a fix for this, but if you're running this straight out of a WP gallery it'd be a lot more difficult to integrate.

Comment: @Pixelsmith what you said got me thinking and I figured out that the problem was being caused by the smush's lazy load feature, I just excluded those galleries and now everything is fine.Thank you so much :D

Comment: Fabulous! Great to hear you were able to resolve it.

You should put your own answer, accept it so that this question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused by the smush's lazy load feature, I just excluded those galleries and now everything is fine